# Calculating energy, in Joules, exerted

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I do not know the relationship between pressure, measured in Pascals, rate of flow of water, and energy, measured in Joules. If one knows the relationship, the solution to this physics problem involves only high school algebra.

A pump pushes 7200 liters of water through hoses each day. The pressure of the water is $10^{4}$ Pascals. How much energy in Joules is exerted by the pump in a year? (Estimate that there are 365.25 days in a year.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(7200 \frac {liters}{day})(\frac{1}{1000}\frac{m^3}{liters})(365.25\frac {days}{years})=2629.8\frac{m^3}{year}$

$10^4 \ \mathrm{Pa}=10^4 \frac{\mathrm{J}}{m^3}$

Total Energy: $(2629.8\frac{m^3}{year})(10^4 \frac{\mathrm{J}}{m^3})=26298000\frac{\mathrm{J}}{year}=26.3\frac{\mathrm{MJ}}{year}$

You may find these articles helpful

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_metre
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(unit)

Comment: I appreciate the links.

Comment: $1 \, \text{Pasca} = 1 \, \text{Joule}/\text{m}^{3}$.